# Delete duplicate sql entries based on distinct Primary Key

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct, sql-delete

I have this table with 3 columns: ID, Account Name, and Primary Key. Some entries have been duplicated where the ID and Account Name are the same but the PK (which is a Primary Key) has been incremented.

I'd like to be able to delete all the duplicate entries EXCEPT for the one with the lowest PK  (Primary Key).

Here's an example of the results from a query I wrote to retrieve just this data:

```
ID          Account Name            PK
18380        _srvSQL               1724
18380        _srvSQL               8454
18380        _srvSQL              10333
18380        _srvSQL               9903
18380        _srvSQL              10274
20993        _svc_MOSS_search      2595
20993        _svc_MOSS_search      9235
21020        _svc_MOSS_WSS         2589
21020        _svc_MOSS_WSS         9244
22251        _SVC_QA_SP_PortalAP   3659
22251        _SVC_QA_SP_PortalAP   9590
22681        _Svc_SQL_AS_Prod      4269
22681        _Svc_SQL_AS_Prod      9678
20136        _svcBIAdmin           1628
20136        _svcBIAdmin          11080
20136        _svcBIAdmin           8913
18456        _svcBizTalk           9923
18456        _svcBizTalk          10294
18456        _svcBizTalk          10353
```

So I can see all the duplicate entries and their distinct Primary Key's, how can I delete all but the one with the lowest Primary Key from the table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WITH t AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY PK) n FROM MyTable)
DELETE FROM t WHERE n > 1
```

Comment: And then a create unique constraint on the `ID` and `Account Name` to keep duplicates at bay.